# How to have jQuery UI tabs evenly occupy the tabs area without any space following by?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, css

If I use jQuery-UI tabs, it often give me an space on the right of the tabs like following:

[image]

You saw above, there is a big space after the three tabs. How to remove the space to have whatever number of tabs to be evenly occupy the tabs area without any space following by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox and then add a polyfill, here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tBwRL/

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box; 
  display: box; 
}


.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: -7px;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: center;  
}
```